# automobiles >as they relate to people< - What does the *as* clause modify?

Tags: meaning, secondary-predicates

Two troublesome noun phrases:

> A "automobiles ***as they existed in the 1950s***"
>   B "automobiles ***as they relate to people***"

The first noun phrase seems to be complete in and of itself, because "*as they existed in the 1950s*" deals exclusives with "*automobiles*" and does not seem to refer to anything outside of the phrase.
But the second noun phrase seems to be incomplete, because "*as they relate to people*" appears needing to refer to something else outside the phrase.

The incompleteness of noun phrase B stands out even more when both phrases are used in a complete sentence:

> 1  He described automobiles ***as they existed in the 1950s***.
>   2  He described automobiles ***as they relate to people***.

In sentence 1, "*he described*" does not appear to be modified by the "*as they existed in the 1950s*", because "*as they existed in the 1950s*" gives information about some intrinsic property of automobiles.
Yet in sentence 2, "*as they relate to people*" appears to modify "*he described*" by showing the manner of "describing".

In another word, "*as they existed in the 1950s*" in sentence 1 seems to be contained completely within the noun phrase "*automobiles as they existed in the 1950s*".
But, "as they relate to people" in sentence 2 seems to be spill outside the noun phrase "*automobiles as they relate to people*" and modifies "*he describes*".
Does anyone think that noun phrase B is, by itself,  incomplete?

Comment: Nope, nothing wrong with it at all.

Comment: If I look at these examples *as they relate to [pragmatics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragmatics)*, I don't really see much difference. #1 requires us to restrict our concept of *automobiles* to those which existed in the 50s (not *as they are today*, for example). By the same token, #2 invites us to focus on those aspects of automobiles which are significant to people (we're not considering their relationship with [roadkill](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/roadkill), for example).

Comment: @FumbleFingers  But regarding the noun phrases, is phrase B not as self-contained as phrase A?

Comment: @meatie: I'm not clear what you mean by "self-contained". Bear in mind *cars as they existed in the 50s* isn't quite the same as *cars **that** existed then*. The former (and *cars as they relate to people*) is a rather loose "abstract noun phrase" denoting a tightly-defined topic of conversation. Superficially you might think you can use ***that*** in the first example without really changing the meaning. But if you try that with the second example *(cars **that** relate to people)*, you should be able to see a glaring difference that isn't really about "completeness, being self-contained".

Comment: @FumbleFingers So, what does "*automobiles* ***as they relate to people***" mean, if "*as they*" cannot be replaced by "*that*"?

Comment: @meatie: I clarified that in my first comment. *"Cars as they relate to people"* is a rather bizarre noun phrase, but it can only really mean *the **aspects** of cars relevant to people*, which implies *aspects of **all** cars*. If you replace ***as they*** with ***that*** you have an even more nonsensical noun phrase meaning some specific subset of all cars - including only those cars which relate to people, not the cars which *don't* relate to people (whatever that means). It's an awkward example because valid real-world referents are so hard to conceptualise.

Answer (score 1):

To begin with, you are wrong in supposing that *as they existed in the 1950s* necessarily refers to an “intrinsic property”. *Exist* embraces both intrinsic and extrinsic properties; indeed, a very prominent school of modern philosophy holds that human essence is a mere epiphenomenon of existence.

Both *as they existed in the 1950s* and *as they relate to people* are restrictions not on actual automobiles but on the **topic** automobiles—automobiles ***as*** a topic of discussion, if you like. *As they existed in the 1950s* excludes *as they existed in the 1940s* and *as they existed in the 1960s*, and so forth, but ignores other possible restrictions, such as the sociological *as they relate to people*. Likewise, *as they relate to people* excludes *as they relate to the environment* and *as they relate to the economy* and even (as FumbleFingers mentions) *as they relate to roadkill*, but ignores historical restrictions.

Note, by the way, that it is possible to incorporate both of these restrictions in  your sentence:

> He described automobiles as they related to people in the 1950s.

In all these cases the *as* clause selects a broader or narrower aspect of the global topic *automobiles* as the topic for immediate discussion.

We might treat any topic the same way. We might, for instance, discuss you, meatie, **as** a child: meatie **as** he existed umpty-years ago, excluding your subsequent schooling and girlfriends and job history. Or we might discuss your role on this site: meatie **as** he relates to ELL, excluding your relationships with family and friends and co-workers and fellow-citizens.

As for the suggestion that *as they relate to people* modifies *described*: 
I raised this question on [ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/182062/24489) and no one seemed to grasp what we were talking about. I have since come to the tentative conclusion that the *as* clause is a sort of secondary object-oriented complement to the verb *discuss*. *Discuss* is not modified by the *as* clause; rather, *discuss* licences and elicits this qualification of *automobiles*.

It may be that *as they relate to people* does not in fact work that way, and someone will come up with a better description.  But however it works, *as they existed in the 1950s* works the same way.

Comment: Is "automobiles as they relate to people" closer to "*automobiles*" or "*automobiles' relation to people*"?

Comment: @Meatie "automobiles in their relation to people"